# Unity 2021 Orbit mode not woking in visual scripting inside Graph Inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine

If you try to go around in your graph inspector in unity 2021 using alt and drag or hand tool, none of it is working except middle mouse click. It was working in the earlier versions, but not in this version.
Is there setup to be configured for it?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, need to change control scheme to unreal